# Elegant way to parse a C array from python

Tags: python

Is there any elegant way to parse a C array and to extract elements with defined indexes to an out file.

For example:

myfile.c

```
my_array[SPECIFIC_SIZE]={
0x10,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x23,0x01,0x02,0x04,0x07,0x08,
0x33,0x97,0x52,0x27,0x56,0x11,0x99,0x97,0x95,0x77,0x23,
0x45,0x97,0x90,0x97,0x68,0x23,0x28,0x05,0x66,0x99,0x38,
0x11,0x37,0x27,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x66,0x09,0x88,0x17,
0x90,0x97,0x17,0x90,0x97,0x22,0x77,0x97,0x87,0x25,0x22,
0x25,0x47,0x97,0x57,0x97,0x67,0x26,0x62,0x67,0x69,0x96
}
```

Python script:

I would like to do something like (just as pseudocode)

```
def parse_data():
    outfile = open(newfile.txt,'w')
    with open(myfile, 'r')
    SEARCH FOR ELEMENT WITH INDEX 0 IN my_array
        COPY ELEMENT TO OUTFILE AND LABEL WITH "Version Number"

    SEARCH FOR ALL ELEMENTS WITH INDEX 1..10 IN my_array
        COPY ELEMENTS TO OUTFILE WITH NEW LINE AND LABEL with "Date"

   ....
   ....
```

At the end I would like to have an newfile.txt like:

```
Version Number:
0x10

Date:
0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x23,0x01,0x02,0x04,0x07,0x08
```

Can you show an example on that pseudocode?

Comment: The myfile.c **only** contains this ? Or are there some different patterns ?

Comment: If myfile.c is actually a valid C file, the real approach is to use a C parser and then look for the AST node declaring the variable that you're interested in. If myfile.c looks exactly like what you pasted: `open('myfile.c').read()[1:-1].replace('\n', '').split(',')` (except use `with open('myfile.c')`, I can't type the with in this comment)

Comment: The only "elegant" way to do it (as in really solid) is to actually parse the C file (assuming it is syntactically correct), for example with [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) or [llvmpy](http://www.llvmpy.org/) (e.g. [see here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang)). But that may be overkill, if you can make some assumptions about the structure and formatting of the files maybe you can work it out with some regex and/or custom logic...

Comment: @IMCoins: Yes it looks  like this, containing only an C array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `.c` file is always parsed like this, as in :

- First line is the declaration of the array.
- Middle lines are the data.
- Last line is the closing bracket.

You can do...

```
def parse_myfile(fileName; outName):
    with open(outName, 'w') as out:
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
            """ 1. Read all lines, except first and last.
                2. Join all the lines together.
                3. Replace all the '\n' by ''.
                4. Split using ','.
            """
            lines = (''.join(f.readlines()[1:-1])).replace('\n', '').split(',')

            header = lines[0]
            date = lines[1:11]
        out.write('Version Number:\n{}\n\nDate:\n{}'.format(header, date))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fileName = 'myfile.c'
    outFile = 'output.txt'
    parse_myfile(fileName, outFile)
```

`cat output.txt` outputs...

```
Version Number:
0x10

Date:
['0x12', '0x13', '0x14', '0x15', '0x23', '0x01', '0x02', '0x04', '0x07', '0x08']
```